# Azure Functions Dropbox multiple user authorization

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have read [Azure Functions External File bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file) and [Get started with the Dropbox connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-dropbox) and I think I understand how to link my Dropbox account to my Azure Function.

The problem is that I don't know how to do this if I want to provide a service to end users. For example user1, user2, user3 need to link their Dropbox accounts to my app (running on Azure) in order to let my function to read/write on their Dropbox folders.

How am I supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I don't know how to do this if I want to provide a service to end users. For example user1, user2, user3 need to link their Dropbox accounts to my app (running on Azure) in order to let my function to read/write on their Dropbox folders.

Per my understanding, you need to use the [user-based authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#auth) for your azure function, but the Dropbox is not supported as the build-in social providers. For azure functions, you could build the http trigger endpoints for authenticating with Dropbox, then your azure function would get the permissions to access the dropbox resources for the specific user. For details about the OAuth guide for Dropbox APIs, you could follow [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide).

Additionally, you could use the OWIN cookie authentication middleware [Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies/) and Dropbox OAuth provider for OWIN [Owin.Security.Providers.Dropbox](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers.Dropbox/) to build your web application and deploy to [azure web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-overview). Moreover, you could follow the similar tutorials below:

[Cookie Authentication in ASP.NET 5](https://dotnetthoughts.net/cookie-authentication-in-asp-net-5/)

[DROPBOX OAUTH WITH ASP.NET MVC STEP BY STEP](https://www.learnmvc.in/aspnet-mvc-identity-with-dropbox-account.php)

Comment: So is the binding at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-external-file just for my own Dropbox account?

Comment: If you have the credentials of other Dropbox accounts, you could manually create the bindings and allow your function to access the files and folders in 
their Dropbox on Azure Portal. Or you need to manually set up the Dropbox OAuth authentication for your app.

Comment: Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: You need to manually build the Dropbox OAuth authentication with your application, and when the users access your application, they would be redirected to Dropbox OAuth authorization endpoint, after users grant the permissions for your app to access their resources, your application would get the `access_token`, then you could leverage the `access_token` to access the resources under the specific user. Details you could follow the tutorials in my answer.

Comment: I couldn't find an example in either C# or node.js. Is this what I need? https://github.com/Huachao/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-connnect-your-app-to-saas-connector.md

Comment: I read the tutorial you provided and I found that I could not find the **Dropbox Connector**, per my understanding it is the build-in web api for you to communicate with Dropbox. I assumed that you need to build the web API by yourself and you could read the tutorials in my answer, also you could follow [dropbox-sdk-dotnet](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet).